# Dodging vertical lines for median_hilow in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot lines that show median and IQR for 3 replicates, across multiple samples.

Data:

```
sampleid <- rep(1:20, each = 3)
replicate <- rep(1:3, 20)
sample1 <- seq(120,197, length.out =  60)
sample2 <- seq(113, 167, length.out = 60)
sample3 <- seq(90,180, length.out = 60)
```

What I have done so far?

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(sampleid,replicate,sample1, sample2, sample3))

library(reshape2) 

long <- melt(df,id.vars = c('sampleid', 'replicate')) 

ggplot(data = long, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = factor(replicate)))   + stat_summary(fun.data=median_hilow, conf.int=.5)
```

However, the plot of the IQR for replicates that I am getting are overlapped with each other for each sample. I would like to find out a way to "dodge" these 3 lines so that they are visible next to each other, without changing other parameters of the plot that I have achieved. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to introduce `jitter` to the lines:

```
ggplot(data = long, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = factor(replicate))) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=median_hilow, fun.args = (conf.int=.5), position = "jitter")
```

Please note you also need to have your `conf.int=5` wrapped in the `fun.args`.

Alternatively, change your `x` to `factor(replicate)` and add `facet_wrap`:

```
ggplot(data = long, aes(x = factor(replicate), y = value, colour = factor(replicate))) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=median_hilow, fun.args = (conf.int=.5)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

Comment: thanks for shedding light on it; I am so close to what I want. But any logic as to why the lines appear randomly for the treatments for different samples? Would it be possible to have these lines appear in sequence, i.e. treatment 1, 2 and 3, and also with equal spacing?

Comment: You are plotting with `x = variable`. This means you are plotting on `sample1`, `sample2` and `sample3` and the lines are all nicely aligned to those. By adding `jitter`, you are able to tell them apart. However, `jitter` adds a random number.

Comment: Have a look at the edit, you might be looking for something like that.